# Account lockout time wrong by 2 hours

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal

When obtaining the time for when an AD user has locked their account, I use the following code:

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, result.SamAccountName);
string = user.AccountLockoutTime.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

However, the time of lockout seems to be off by exactly two hours. What is wrong? Is it timezone related, or is the time on the AD server wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [remarks section of the MSDN documentation on the `AccountLockoutTime` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.accountlockouttime(v=vs.110).aspx):

> As with all DateTime properties in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, the time returned is in UTC form. To convert it to local time, call the ToLocalTime method on the return object.

Use

```
user.AccountLockoutTime.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

to get the date and time in your local timezone.